# Python add to a list that is a value of a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add to a list that is a value of a key in two different (operations?). Below is an example:

```
item['foo'] = ["blah"]
item['foo'] = ["garble"]
```

where `item` is a dictionary and `foo` is a key. Then if I print foo I get:

`["garble"]`

when I want

`["blah", "garble"]`

How do I get the end result I want?

EDIT: formating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want the value to be a list, you should append to `item['foo']` like this:

```
item = {}
item['foo'] = ["blah"]
item['foo'].append("garble")
print(item)
```

which prints out:

```
{'foo': ['blah', 'garble']}
```

If garble is a list, for example something like `garble = ["blah2"]`, you can do list merging like this:

```
item = {}
item['foo'] = ["blah"]
garble = ["blah2"]
item['foo'] += garble
print item
```

Which in turn prints out:

```
{'foo': ['blah', 'blah2']}
```

Comment: garble is a list though, which then prints out:

`foo: ['blah, ['garble']]`

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the dictionary value instead of appending to it, try:

```
item['foo'] = ['blah']
item['foo'].append('garble')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with the code shown is first assigning the value `['blah']` to the key `'foo'`, and then, in the next step, assigning the value `['garble']` to the key `'foo'`.  A key can only be assigned to one value (and by "value", we mean any type, be it an integer, a string, a list, a tuple, etc.), so the second assignment overwrites the first.  What you want is for the key `'foo'` be assigned to the list `["blah", "garble"]`.  The list is one value.  This can be done in one step like this:

```
item['foo'] = ["blah", "garble"]
```

or, if, for some reason, you want to create a key value pair where the value is a list, and then add an item to that list later, this is how you would do it:

```
item['foo'] = ['blah']
item['foo'].append('garble')
```

The first line assigns the list `['blah']` to the key `'foo'`.  The second line retrieves the value assigned to the key `'foo'` from the dictionary `item`, applies the list method `.append()` to it (which will ONLY work if the value retrieved from the dictionary with the key `'foo'` IS in fact a list!), and then appends to that list the string `'garble'`.  The result is:

```
>>> item['foo']
['blah', 'garble']
```

Do NOT do this:

```
item['foo'].append(['garble'])
```

or you will end up with the second element of this list another list, like this:

```
['blah', ['garble']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Close you just need to append it

```
item = dict()

item['foo'] = ["blah"]
#above sets key foo to list value blah
#either of below appends a new value to the foo's list
item['foo'] += ["garble"] 
#or item['foo'].append("garble")
#note if this method is used list notation is needed to stop interpretation
# of each character. So I'd use append but wanted to show how close you were

print item
#outputs: {'foo': ['blah', 'garble']}
```

@PythonNoob see the comment if += works for you it works but .append would be the preferred method and I'd also look at @Zizouz212 answer as the extend feature is a useful addition.

Comment: I'll point out, using methods produces much cleaner, and much more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values of the key:

```
>>> item["foo"] = ["bar"] # bar is the value
```

If bar is a list, you can use all of the methods that are already associated with it. Here we use `append`.

```
>>> item["foo"].append("meh")
>>> item["foo"]
["bar", "meh"]
```

Of course, if you want to add a list (and have it be "merged"), you the `extend` method.

```
>>> item["foo"].extend(["gar", "ble"])
>>> item["foo"]
["bar", "meh", "gar", "ble"]
```

If you don't use `extend` there, you'll have a nested list:

```
["bar", "meh", ["gar", "ble"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in combination with [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> dd[1].extend([2]) # You can now do stuff like this without initialization
>>> dd[1].extend((3, 4)) # No worries, hakuna matata style
>>> dd[1]
[2, 3, 4]
```

In my opinion, this makes the code very simple and clean.

You can also use [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add a single element to the list instead of all the elements of an iterable:

```
>>> dd[1].append(5)
>>> dd[1]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdefault`. It would try to look for `'foo'` at first; if it cannot find it, `setdefault` would add `'foo'` to `item` dictionary, with corresponding value as `[]`, and would also return the reference to this value. To this returned value, you can append entries from `vals` list.

If `setdefault` is able to find the key `'foo'` in the dictionary, it simply returns the corresponding value for it, which would again be a list.

```
item = {}
vals = ['blah', 'garble']

for x in vals:
    item.setdefault('foo', []).append(x)
print item['foo']         # print ['blah', 'garble']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> item = {}
>>> item['foo'] = ["blah"]
>>> item['foo'].append("garble")
>>> item
{'foo': ['blah', 'garble']}
>>>
```